# Cannot get videos with photoManager in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to build a custom gallery in my app like the one in Instagram when you want to post a reel. I tried to do that but I couldn't. I don't know what I'm missing and I know I'm missing something because no one have the same issue.

The media in the code is only returning images. I have the latest version of photo manager and also I added the required permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

Here is the output if we print media:

> I/flutter (10353): [AssetEntity(id: 1000000043 , type: AssetType.image), AssetEntity(id: 1000000042 , type: AssetType.image), AssetEntity(id: 1000000041 , type: AssetType.image), AssetEntity(id: 1000000040 , type: AssetType.image), AssetEntity(id: 1000000039 , type: AssetType.image), AssetEntity(id: 1000000038 , type: AssetType.image), AssetEntity(id: 1000000037 , type: AssetType.image), AssetEntity(id: 1000000036 , type: AssetType.image), AssetEntity(id: 1000000035 , type: AssetType.image), AssetEntity(id: 1000000033 , type: AssetType.image)]

Only images even though I have videos.

**MY CODE**

```
_fetchNewMedia() async {
  lastPage = currentPage;
  final PermissionRequestOption requestOption = PermissionRequestOption(
    androidPermission: const AndroidPermission(
      type: RequestType(1),
      mediaLocation: false,
    ),
  );

  final PermissionState ps = await PhotoManager.requestPermissionExtend(
    requestOption: requestOption,
  );
  print(ps);

  final List<AssetPathEntity> paths = await PhotoManager.getAssetPathList(
    hasAll: true,
    type: RequestType.all,
  );

  print(paths);

  AssetPathEntity recentAlbum = paths.firstWhere(
    (album) => album.name == "Recent",
    orElse: () => paths.first,
  );

  // Fetch media from the selected album
  List<AssetEntity> media = await recentAlbum.getAssetListPaged(
    page: currentPage,
    size: 60,
  );
  print(media);

  List<AssetEntity> videoMedia =
      media.where((asset) => asset.type == AssetType.video).toList();

  print(videoMedia);

  List<Widget> temp = [];
  for (var asset in media) {
    temp.add(
      FutureBuilder(
        future: asset.thumbnailDataWithSize(const ThumbnailSize(200, 200)),
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned.fill(
                  child: Image.memory(
                    snapshot.data!,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                if (asset.type == AssetType.video)
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5, bottom: 5),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.videocam,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            );
          }
          return Container();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
  setState(() {
    _mediaList.addAll(temp);
    currentPage++;
  });
}
```

I tried everything reading documentation asking every ai I know searched for similar issues but nothing worked I think the problem is with my code I am missing something